# Robo Script crawls only MainActvity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

My Robo Script crawls only MainActivity and Activites with

```
android:parentActivityName =".MainAcvitiy`
```

But I recorded all Activites

It ignores Intents like:

```
public static void enableNavigation(final Context context, BottomNavigationViewEx viewEx){
    viewEx.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.ic_home:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class); //ACTIVITY_NUM = 0
                    context.startActivity(intent1);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_search:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, SwipeActivity.class); // ACTIVITY_ NUM = 1
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_cookbook:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, CookBookActivity.class); //ACTIVITY_NUM = 2
                    context.startActivity(intent3);
                    break;

                case R.id.ic_shoppinglist:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, ShoppingListActivity.class); // ACTIVITY_NUM = 3
                    context.startActivity(intent4);
                    break;
            }
```

> My RoboScript for ACTIVITY_NUM = 1

```
 {
    "className": "android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 1,
    "resourceId": "com.mrriegl.cook_thinking_01:id/ic_search",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "com.mrriegl.cook_thinking_01:id/bottomNavViewBar",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  }
```

> Activity_NUM = 2

```
{
"eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
"timestamp": 1538124993290,
"replacementText": "",
"actionCode": -1,
"delayTime": 0,
"canScrollTo": false,
"elementDescriptors": [
  {
    "className": "android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 2,
    "resourceId": "com.mrriegl.cook_thinking_01:id/ic_cookbook",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "com.mrriegl.cook_thinking_01:id/bottomNavViewBar",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  }
]
```

> ACTIVITY_NUM = 3

```
{
"eventType": "VIEW_CLICKED",
"timestamp": 1538125003638,
"replacementText": "",
"actionCode": -1,
"delayTime": 0,
"canScrollTo": false,
"elementDescriptors": [
  {
    "className": "android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 3,
    "resourceId": "com.mrriegl.cook_thinking_01:id/ic_shoppinglist",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "className": "com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx",
    "recyclerViewChildPosition": -1,
    "adapterViewChildPosition": -1,
    "groupViewChildPosition": 0,
    "resourceId": "com.mrriegl.cook_thinking_01:id/bottomNavViewBar",
    "contentDescription": "",
    "text": ""
  }
```

> I'm confused why an event has 3 elements, the first element is each
>   correct:

```
groupViewChildPosition: 1 = Activity Num 1
groupViewChildPosition: 2 = Activity Num 2
groupViewChildPosition: 3 = Activity Num 3
```

**What about the other 2 with groupViewChildPosition: 0**

This is my first Android app, unfortunately I have not found anything on the internet, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) Robo starts an app using its main activity first and applies Robo script right away, and thus, a Robo script is applied to main activity. At the same time, your Robo script might span multiple activities, the only constraint is that the recording should start with the main activity (i.e., your app can go from one activity to another during Robo script recording, and it should be recorded and replayed by Robo correctly, if the first activity is MainActivity).

2) An element is identified by its own attributes (e.g., resourceId) and attributes of the element's two immediate parents. Therefore, every element has three blocks with attributes - for itself, for the immediate parent, and for the immediate parent's parent. So, in your example, "groupViewChildPosition: 0" attributes belong to the element's parent nodes.